# Titlebar of the windows is not showing up

Tags: 11.10, unity, titlebar

I can't see the titlebar anymore. The one with the close and minimize buttons, unless the window is in full screen. Here is an image:

[image: My problem]

Comment: Your unity just crash. Log out and login again. Or run " unity --reset "(without quote) in terminal. Upgrade your unity package if it is a permanent problem. You can do this easily from synaptic manager.

Comment: I think I've run into the same problem, I just haven't taken the time to try and permanently fix it. I was able to band-aid it by I think minimizing the window, or switching to another window and switching back. I don't recall what it was exactly but I've always been able to get the command bar to show again after a couple minutes of fiddling. A real solution would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned the version of ubuntu and whether are you in unity. I assume that you are in **unity** as its a frequent problem in unity and ubuntu version is equal to or more than **11.04**

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Login using your username and password
- Reset compiz by executing `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`
- Reset unity , by executing `unity --reset`
- Optionally you can reset launcher icons by executing `unity --reset-icons`
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to login screen. However I recommend a restart by executing `sudo reboot`

Probably you have set something wrong in `compiz`. If so include more details for help

Comment: why should he reset the compiz settings?

Comment: Most of the times wrong compiz settings cause unity to crash.